# Rounding up text in Qlikview

Tags: text, qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I am trying to round up the outcome of the text below.
I know the `€ #.##0` probably needs to be placed at the ends, but I can not get it to work icw to the brackets etc. Thank you in advance.

```
=if(SUM(EM)>= 400000, 

num((((SUM(EM)-400000)*0.0118)+12000),'€ #.##0')/count(DISTINCT PersonId),

num(SUM(EM)*0,03,'€ #.##0')/count(DISTINCT PersonId)

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try only putting the formatting around the solution

```
=num(
    if(SUM(EM)>= 400000,

        ((SUM(EM)-400000)*0.0118+12000)/count(DISTINCT PersonId),

        SUM(EM)*0.03/count(DISTINCT PersonId)
     )
 ,'€ #.##0')
```

Comment: No worries, now you need to give me my magic internet points and please mark the answer correct